# Can you refer to the object being called within a class object function?

Tags: c++, function, class

I am trying to create a function within my class definition that uses two class objects. I would like to enter the first object as the parameter of the function and the second object as the object that is being called e.g: ClassObject1.function(ClassObject2)

My question is how do i refer to the object being called, ClassObject1, within the function?

Comment: That object is `*this`.  So you could write `(*this).function(ClassObject2)` or equally well `this->function(ClassObject2)`  But what is wrong with just `function(ClassObject2)`?  (In ordinary classes the `this->` is implied wherever needed).

Comment: `this`. First 10 pages of your C++ book.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is really clear. `this` shouldn't be necessary from the class's own member functions. I'd like clarification from the OP (and maybe some code, even if it's broken).

Comment: Maybe the wording of the question confused us regarding which object is which.  Maybe the syntax being requested is `OtherObject.function(*this)`

Comment: minus wun for the first Google hit having the answer in the title.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer that refers to the object the member function was called for.

Usually you need `this` when you want to return reference to the object or to create a copy of the object inside the member function.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how do i refer to the object being called, ClassObject1, within the function?

The keyword `this` is a pointer to the object on which the function was called. Inside a non-static member function, you can use `this` to refer to the object.

```
void MyClass::function(MyClass obj2)
{
    std::cout << "The address of the current object is: " << (void*)this << std::endl;

    // Call another member function on the same object.
    this->function2();

}
```

See [more on `this` pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this).